# Contact form won't send from Magento says Unable to submit your request

Tags: magento, contact-form

I just upgraded the new version of Magento and noticed that our contact form on our site doesn't work anymore it just says "Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later".

I created email.log and it outputted: 
DEBUG (7): true;'My Name';'email@domain.com';'Contact Form'

I tried with new upgrade for community and Enterprise and they are both outputting the same error on the contact forms. Reading around on forums they say it has to do with Magento not setting it's setting with new the new ZEND mail.

I've tried literally 20 different things:

- Verified the contact was enabled in the backend, 
  set Send Emails To: myemail@email.com 
  Email Sender: General Contact
  Email Template: Contact Form (Default Template from Locale)
- Went to mail sending settings on ADVANCED_System 
  Disable Email Communications was set to no
  Made sure Set return path was set to YES, even changed it No, and specified and still   didn't work even after clearing cache after saving the settings
- Changed the template.php
- Made sure   was between the submit button in form.phtml located in (app\design\ frontend\enterprise\default\template\contacts)
- Checked IndexController.php located in (app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers)
- Checked Mail.php to see if there was anything interesting. (lib\Zend)

I'm really lost for answers and I've searched high and low, even on here and haven't found a solution to work. My contact form and everything was working before I upgraded to the new version. I even tried community version on a fresh install with just a few dummy products and it outputs the same error.

---

Thank you everyone for your feedback, I've decided after 8 hours to just forget that solution and go to use this free solution: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ziq2004/extension/460/advanced-smtp--artson.it

It basically lets you set your SMTP settings and blocks the original local one Magento says to use. Hope someone else can save hours through that solution.

Comment: couple of questions: which version did you upgrade from? is it possible you are missing something on the actual server? I'd check the Magento dependencies and make sure everything is installed

Comment: Inside the IndexController.php, you could start logging at different states to find out when the exception is being thrown. There's only a few places. It's probably at line ~106, getSentSuccess(). If it's earlier, that's just some form validation so that should be easy to fix (maybe the input fields have different name attributes now or something?) Also, double check your file permissions.

Comment: No result after all this time?